# platform.win32.Win32Exception: The data is invalid | Java

Tags: java, winapi, encryption

I was writing this code to restore the user's saved chrome passwords and display them on the console.
I was able to decode Base64 encoded. But I am failing in decrying from this **Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData** any help ...
I am a beginner. :)
**Main.java**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = System.getProperty("user.home");
        name += "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\";
        String masterKey = "";
        String localState = name + "Local State";
        try {
            Object object = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(localState));
            System.out.println("Success");
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
            JSONObject tempJsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("os_crypt");
            Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            String encryptedKey = (String) tempJsonObject.get("encrypted_key");
            String decryptedKey = new String(decoder.decode(encryptedKey));
            String encryptedMasterKey = decryptedKey.substring(5);
            System.out.println(encryptedMasterKey);
            masterKey = new String(Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(encryptedMasterKey.getBytes()));
            System.out.println(masterKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Success
[value of **encryptedMasterKey**]
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The data is invalid.
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:144)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:117)
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:104)
    at com.main.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decoder.decode()` returns **binary data**. You cannot create a `String` from binary data.

If you want a `byte[]` with the first 5 bytes from the `byte[]` returned by `decoder.decode()`, use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-byte:A-int-int-):

```java
String encryptedKey = (String) tempJsonObject.get("encrypted_key");

Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] decodedKey = decoder.decode(encryptedKey);
byte[] encryptedMasterKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedKey, 0, 5);
byte[] masterKey = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(encryptedMasterKey);
```

However, I doubt that is correct. Why do you believe the master password could be encrypted to only 5 bytes, and what is all the rest then?

It's far more likely that all the bytes are encrypted version of the master key:

```java
String encryptedKey = (String) tempJsonObject.get("encrypted_key");

byte[] masterKey = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedKey));
```

Comment: Your first code worked but with a change of 
```
Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedKey, 5, decodedKey.length);
```
I also have the same thing written in python which is working what I need but it the master key is another format and this master key from java is in other which I don't know but I think it is correct just format is different ... Thank YOU :)

Comment: @NaveedKhan You're thanking me, but you don't think the answer was useful or acceptable? Any answer you find "useful" should be up-voted, by clicking the up-arrow to the left of the answer. You should also "accept" the best answer by clicking the check mark, so others can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Hahaha dear i did it just said to me 
''Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @NaveedKhan Ahh, right. Well, then, welcome to StackOverflow. 

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Andreas is almost correct
I used this code which gave me an exception

```
String encryptedKey = (String) tempJsonObject.get("encrypted_key");

Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] decodedKey = decoder.decode(encryptedKey);
byte[] encryptedMasterKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedKey, 0, 5);
byte[] masterKey = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(encryptedMasterKey);
```

So it just changed some values in

```
String encryptedKey = (String) tempJsonObject.get("encrypted_key");

Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
byte[] decodedKey = decoder.decode(encryptedKey);
byte[] encryptedMasterKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(decodedKey, 5, decodedKey.length);
byte[] masterKey = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(encryptedMasterKey);
```

It worked But now I have to understand its key format :)
Thanks, Andreas